# Creating hyperlink to worksheet in Excel whenever a new sheet is added

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I was wondering if there is an option in Excel that lets you create a hyperlink in the first sheet (let's call it main sheet) to any other sheets once they are created. So once I create a new sheet the hyperlink to it appears in the main sheet.

Comment: You'd have to do this in VBA I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a Worksheets Menu

```
Option Explicit
Sub WsMenu()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Description
  'Writes a list of hyperlinks and various other properties of all sheets in a
  'workbook to a specified worksheet which is not included in the list.
'Preconditions
  'There has to be a worksheet called cStrName in the workbook, which will
  'become the 'Menu' or what ever you wanna call it.
'Arguments as constants
  'cStrName
    'Name of the 'Menu' worksheet.
  'cStrAddress
    'The address on each sheet where the hyperlink will jump to.
  'clRoff
    'If you don't want to start the list in the first row.
  'ciCoff
    'If you don't want to start the list in column "A".

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Const cStrName As String = "Menu"
  Const cStrAddress As String = "A1"
  Const clROff As Long = 0 'Row Offset
  Const ciCOff As Integer = 0 'Column Offset

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Dim oWb As Workbook
  Dim oWs As Worksheet
  Dim oWsMenu As Worksheet
  Dim iSheets As Integer
  Dim strName As String

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set oWb = ThisWorkbook
  Set oWsMenu = oWb.Worksheets(cStrName)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  With oWsMenu
    'Header
    'Clear the previous data (includes the formatting), or rather use
    'ClearContents to preserve the formatting.
    .Cells.Clear

    .Cells(1 + clROff, 1 + ciCOff) = "RID" 'RecordId
    .Cells(1 + clROff, 2 + ciCOff) = "Name"
    .Cells(1 + clROff, 3 + ciCOff) = "CodeName"
    .Cells(1 + clROff, 4 + ciCOff) = "Index" 'The postion of the oWs in oWb
    .Cells(1 + clROff, 5 + ciCOff) = "H" 'Number of Hyperlinks in oWs
    .Cells(1 + clROff, 6 + ciCOff) = "Used Range"

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Calculate and write to 'Menu'
    For Each oWs In oWb.Worksheets

      'You don't want the "Menu" worksheet to appear in the list.
      If oWs.Name <> cStrName Then

        iSheets = iSheets + 1
        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 1 + ciCOff) = iSheets

        'The Hyperlink
        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 2 + ciCOff).Hyperlinks.Add _
          Anchor:=.Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 2 + ciCOff), _
          Address:="", _
          SubAddress:="'" & oWs.Name & "'!" & cStrAddress, _
          TextToDisplay:=oWs.Name
        'Notice the single quotes (') in the SubAddress.

        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 3 + ciCOff) = oWs.CodeName
        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 4 + ciCOff) = oWs.Index
        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 5 + ciCOff) = oWs.Hyperlinks.Count
        .Cells(iSheets + clROff + 1, 6 + ciCOff) = oWs.UsedRange.Address
      End If
    Next

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'This is a work around, a lousy one.
    If .Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
      .Activate
    End If

    'The following line does a 1004 without the previous 3 lines, only when
    'calling the program from a sheet different then 'Menu'. I have no idea why!?

    'Apply some additional formatting.
    With .Range(Cells(1 + clROff, 1 + ciCOff), Cells(1 + clROff, 6 + ciCOff))
      .AutoFilter
      .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

  End With
End Sub
```

Additionally go to sheet events and add this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  WsMenu
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Right click the cell where you want the link and then click `Link`.
- This will open the **Insert Hyperlink** dialog.
- On the left side, click `Place in this document`.
- Choose the worksheet and enter the cell name.

[image: img]

You could do this programmatically with [the `Hyperlinks.Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add).

You could have the links added automatically to/from new worksheets with the `NewSheet` event of the **Workbook** module.

It's also possible to add links to external workbooks, including those published online.

---

Here's a rough example of the code you could use to create a link on the "Main" worksheet every time a new worksheet is created:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim shtName As String, ws As Worksheet, rg As Range
    shtName = InputBox("Enter name for new worksheet:")
    Sh.Name = shtName
    Set ws = Sheets("main")
    Set rg = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rg = shtName
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add rg, "", shtName & "!A1", , shtName
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- MS Office Support : [**Work with hyperlinks in Excel**](https://support.office.com/article/work-with-hyperlinks-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e)
- Lifewire : [**Adding Excel Hyperlinks, Bookmarks, and Mailto Links**](https://www.lifewire.com/hyperlinks-bookmarks-and-mailto-shortcuts-excel-3123635)
- TechRecipes : [**Create a Hyperlink to Another Worksheet or Excel Sheet**](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49296/microsoft-excel-create-a-hyperlink-to-another-worksheet-or-excel-sheet/)
- MS Office Support : [**Using hyperlinks in a workbook in the browser**](https://support.office.com/article/using-hyperlinks-in-a-workbook-in-the-browser-abc4e340-0cf1-426e-9a69-20531b0c9a5f)
- MSDN : [**`Workbook.NewSheet` Event** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet)
- Ozgrid : [**Run Macro Code When New Sheet Added**](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/75698-run-macro-code-when-new-sheet-added)

Comment: I think OP means to create hyperlink automatic when a new sheet is created.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns -  yeah I posted a little prematurely, I've added more info and links.  My point is, one could simply record a macro to capture the addition of the sheet, and then have that run on the `NewSheet` event.

Comment: Indeed, but I posted that because I saw the downvote and I guess it was because of that

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I appreciate it, thanks. I added some code.